# SQL to HQL - date conversion issue

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am looking to convert the following SQL into HQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.aid from atable a, btable b 
where a.aid=b.id and 
STR_TO_DATE(a.somecolumn, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND CURDATE();
```

In short, we have a date stored as string in one of the columns in our table. Want to use the same in HQL to get records for a certain range.

Can this be done using a single HQL?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working using DATEDIFF function-

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.aid from atable a, btable b 
where a.aid=b.id and DATEDIFF(current_date(), a.somecolumn) < 10
```

The date in *a.somecolumn* is stored in the format **yyyy-MM-dd** but as a *string* (a.somecolumn type is varchar). May need to check what other formats are supported by DATEDIFF function by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria.add(Restrictions.between("propertyName","startDate", "endDate"))
```

Comment: Want HQL for the same, not using Criteria.

Comment: select i from Invoice i where i.Date between :start and :end ";

Comment: The issue is that the date is stored as string.